# CocoonJS webview: Going back a page

Tags: cocoonjs

I'm just trying out a simple app in the CocoonJS launcher which contains some links that open some external page.

This works fine, but the problem is that I can't identify a way to go back a page (i.e. history back). The launcher app just displays the page in fullscreen, no user controls visible at all. This is troublesome, because when my users tap on an ad, I want them to be able to go back to the game.

Am I missing something or is this simply not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of any way to display a navigation bar or something similar.
Nevertheless, you can open your external urls via Cocoon.App.openURL(url); which will enable the user to open it via a normal browser where you can navigate back.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the solution proposed by Scdev. Also, interstitials or fullscreen ads usually have a dismiss button themselves. I might be misunderstanding something.

Regards,
Iker.